# Visual Studio Store Menu Missing

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've been searching online for an answer and I can't find it.  I don't seem to have a menu for the Microsoft Store to create an application package.  I'm using Windows 8.1.

I've tried Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2015.  I've downloaded Update 4 for 2012 and SDK 2015 download.  The Store menu is not available in either vb or C# projects.  However, I'm relatively new to VS and am sure there's probably a good chance the error is on my end.

My understanding is that the Store menu is accessed via the Project > Store menu or by right-clicking the project and selecting Store.  In neither of these instances does the Store menu actually show up in my case.

Comment: Did you create your project from a *Windows Store* template, e.g. Windows Phone, Windows 8.1, Universal Windows etc.? The menu is not available for all types of projects, such as classic desktop applications, class libraries etc.

Comment: Oh, yep, that's my problem then.  From searching online, it looks like there's no way to upload a classic desktop application to the store, is that correct?

Comment: AFAIK, that is still the case. At Build 2015 they [announced plans](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/3210/build-2015-microsoft-will-allow-desktop-applications-in-windows-store) for allowing classic desktop apps to the store, but I haven't heard about it since.

Comment: Please refer the below https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/df85de3a-df51-4a66-ac0a-6ec96e0be217/no-quotstorequot-menu-on-visual-studio-community-2015-on-windows-10?forum=visualstudiogeneral